# What is the outcome of energy measurement if you have a superposition state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I was thinking that in a superposition state that the energy measurement will be the sum of the respective energies. Is this wrong? I know that the expectation value of the energy is given by $\langle H \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |c_n|^2E_n$, but I'm not sure this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you measure energy, you will put the system in an energy eigenstate. The measured value will be one of the eigenvalues.

The superpostion amplitudes will help you calculate the probability of each outcome.